# Path: Shared Users & Drive

Tags: shared-directory

I have been trying to create a link, you can say either as an hyperlink or a kind of automation that is like I have a template which I paste it to my Gmail message and send it out to my team.

When they receive my mail they just have to click the path mentioned in the template. When clicked I want the exact folder to be popped out for them instead of going through all the locations and then to the destination.

So my question is: Is there a way for me to give away the path a link, so that any shared user can click and open the exact folder at the same time in any number of computers?

**Example:**  C:\Users\ketan\Pictures\a\”destination”  -  **An hyperlink to these kind of URL's should take them to the “Destination” directly in one click**

Comment: Would it be specific to Internet explorer and/or windows mail client ? please specify

Comment: @dvhh It's neither to internet explorer or windows mail client but drives (C/D/E/F) under "My computers" Example: C:\Users\ketan\Videos\Debut -> I want shared users to open debut folder mentioned in the above URL in one click rather going through all places so which why i need a hyperlink.

Comment: To clarify my question : Is it limited to Windows or are you also targetting Linux, MacOS, iOS, Android, Solaris ... etc

Comment: @dvhh: For now iam targetting just the Windows but we can even work on others too

Answer (score 0):

Handling such link is usually considering a **security issue** inside a web browser, as it can allow to discover arbitra.ry resource on the local machine/ local network. So having such link is usually discouraged.

if you are only considering local resource the `file://` protocol handler would be sufficient, but in most can the link would be handled by the internet browser (link to a file would trigger a download from the local filesystem, link to a directory would display a file list of the directory), and not the file manager.

Mail client usually handle html links via the default web browser.

Comment: Your right on the security issue part which is why iam striking hard so that i can avoid such security issues or any downloads but no luck, Pl advise.... also any software usage is strictly prohibited so I have to work with this too